# insert if not exists Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

my controller:

```
function getFeed()
{
   $feed_url = $this->input->get("url");
   $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
   $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        $feeds[] = array(
                         'title' => (string)$entry->title,
                         'url'=> (string)$entry->link,
                         'username' => $this->session->userdata('username')                      
                );

        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->membership_model->feeds($feeds);
    }
```

Model:

```
function feeds($feeds_data)
{   
        $this->db->insert_batch('feeds', $feeds_data);
}
```

Is there a function to insert if only the row doesn't exists in the table? I have a table with 4 column : id,title,url,username. I have an anchor when i click him it calls geFeed function and insert the info into table. But i want to insert only if not exists.

Comment: if you do have to check the database for every feed to see if its already there - i'm wondering if it will be more efficient to get the feeds from the database table as an object or array - and then check against that. versus hitting the database table for every feed.

Comment: can u help me with a solution? i've tried to put after insert batch a command who deletes the duplicate rows but it not works $this->db->query('DELETE FROM feeds WHERE title = ANY (SELECT title FROM feeds))

Comment: I've searched on google and i don't find a solution for this

Answer (score 3):

I had the same challenge, so i eventually come up with a function which might be helpful to you.

```
    function safe_update_batch($table_name,$records,$filter_field)
    {
        $filters=array();

        foreach($records as $record)$filters[]=$record[$filter_field];

        $this->db->query("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=10000000");

        $query=$this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT($filter_field) AS existing_keys",FALSE)->where_in($filter_field, $filters)->get($table_name);

        $row=$query->row();
        $found_fields=explode(',',$row->existing_keys);         

        $insert_batch=array();
        $update_batch=array();

        foreach($records as $record)
        {
            if(in_array($record[$filter_field],$found_fields))$update_batch[]=$record;
            else $insert_batch[]=$record;
        }

        if(!empty($insert_batch))$this->db->insert_batch($table_name,$insert_batch);
        if(!empty($update_batch))$this->db->update_batch($table_name,$update_batch,$filter_field);      
    }
```

//sample usage

```
$this->safe_update_batch('feeds', $feeds_data,'title');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your model!!

```
function insertClient($array)
{

        $this->db->from('MyTable');
        $this->db->where('Id', $array['Id']); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() != 0){
            $data = array(
                        'name'=>$array['name'],
                        'phone'=>$array['phone'],
                        'email'=>$array['email']
                     );

         $this->db->where('Id', $array['Id']);
         $this->db->update('CLIENTS', $data); 
        }else{
            $data = array(
            'name'=>$array['name'],
                        'phone'=>$array['phone'],
                        'email'=>$array['email']
            );
           $this->db->insert('CLIENTS',$data);
        }

}
```

In controller:

```
$this->site_model->insertClient($_POST);
```

Comment: Welcome @Daniel, can you add some explanation about what you modified to the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly if you are using the active record class an `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` function doesn't exist.  You could try

- Extending the active record class (easier said than done)
- You could set indexes on certain columns as UNIQUE so that MySQL will check to see if it already exists
- You could do some kind of `SELECT` before your `INSERT` to determine if the record is already there
- For the queries where you need to do `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` do `$this->db->query('INSERT IF NOT EXISTS...')`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFeed()
{

    // Load the model up here - otherwise you are loading it multiple times 
    $this->load->model('membership_model');

   $feed_url = $this->input->get("url");
   $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
   $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {

    // check if the feed is unique, if true then add to array
    if( $this->membership_model->singleFeedIsUnique($entry) == TRUE  ){     
         $feeds[] = array(
                         'title' => (string)$entry->title,
                         'url'=> (string)$entry->link,
                         'username' => $this->session->userdata('username')); }               

    } //foreach

      // check to make sure we got any feeds with isset()
      // if yes, then add them
      if (isset($feeds)){ $this->membership_model->feeds($feeds); }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your model and leave you controller without changes

```
function feeds($feeds_data)
{
    $data = array(
        title => $feeds_data[0],
        url => $feeds_data[1],
        username => $feeds_data[2]
        );
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('mytable');
    $this->db->where('title',$feeds_data[0]);//you can use another field
    if ($this->db->count_all_results() == 0) {
      $query = $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);//insert data
    } else {
      $query = $this->db->update('mytable', $data, array('title'=>$feeds_data[0]));//update with the condition where title exist
    }
}
```

you can check the id if you have it, adding in the data array and use it to check if exist